# Cannot post images to Slack channel via web hooks utilizing Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, bots, webhooks, slack-api

I'm attempting to post an image to a Slack channel utilizing web hooks.  This basic setup has allowed me to post text to the channel, but I've been unable to post the image.  Here's my code:

```
def posting():
    import requests
    import json

    url = 'https://webhook'
    image = {'media': open('trial.jpg', 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url, files=image)
    r.json
```

When I post the text, a web hook bot appears in the channel and posts it.  Do I need some further authentication to post?  Or is it a matter of Slack having their own API for uploading and wants me to go through that?  Or something something bots don't have rights to post images?

I took a look at some other questions here, but they didn't appear to be using web hooks or bots, so I'm not sure if my issue is something involving those.

Comment: I'm not sure how you decided on that payload, but maybe read https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks for the expected inputs? (I think you want to be sending JSON with an `attachments` element.)

Comment: I took a look at the slack APIs, and it appears that for attachments, they're always expecting a URL.  I'd prefer to simply upload a file from a directory.  The requests library makes it seem like this will be possible, but I'm not used enough to coding to know when I'm banging my head against the wall to follow my original plan instead of just changing my setup to work with documentation in front of me.  Is that one of those times?

Comment: I think so. I'm pretty sure (per the documentation) that "incoming webhooks" don't have any option that allows uploading a file, so you'll need to put the file elsewhere and attach it via a URL.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this through the Slack API using their files.upload method: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

You will need an API auth token for this to work properly.  You can set up a testing token or follow the instructions to register your program to get a long term one: https://api.slack.com/web#basics

Also, 'media' doesn't seem to be the right json key to use for file uploads:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Here's an example using requests to send an image to a channel.  Use '@username' if you want the image to go to a specific user.  I've included the content type and header but it should work without them as well.
This will print the response from Slack.

```
import requests

def post_image(filename, token, channels):
    f = {'file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'image/png', {'Expires':'0'})}
    response = requests.post(url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload', data=
       {'token': token, 'channels': channels, 'media': f}, 
       headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, files=f)
    return response.text

print post_image(filename='path/to/file.png', token='xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx',
    channels ='#general')
```